# What is the difference between creating a plugin in QGIS 3.x and writing a python standalone script in QGIS 3.x?

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3

I am developing a plugin in QGIS where I have used the template "Tool button with dialog". I am using this tutorial: http://g-sherman.github.io/Qgis-Plugin-Builder/ and https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/building_a_python_plugin.html . However, I came across this http://www.qgistutorials.com/fi_FI/docs/processing_python_scripts.html where a python standalone script in the processing toolbox will also easily create a similar user interface. Which one is more user friendly and what is the advantage?

Comment: Is the question still too broad..?